# Why are absolute sizes displayed as different sizes on mobile browsers?

Tags: android, html, css

I'm currently trying to develop a simple web app for both desktop and tablet browsers. Everything works perfectly on the desktop and almost so on the tablet except a small size change that causes elements to be thrown into the wrong position.

Initially I had all elements margins, widths etc. defined in pixel values that I assumed would create consistency. However, in chrome for desktop an element defined as 339px including margins was 339px, but on chrome for android, remote debugging revealed it to be 346px even with the same CSS defining it as 339px, causing an overlap and hence strange layout.

After some digging I heard tell of the viewport meta tag that would cause different rendering on mobile browsers. However, after the addition of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

To try and force the mobile browser to behave like a desktop, the browser rendered it no differently.

Finally I tried changing the pixel values to em values to allow for a little more play if the font sizes were different and still no luck. I have rather run out of ideas as of now so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be to do with pixel density differences- I have had the same issue myself.  *EDIT* No, it would still be the same amount of pixels methinks.

Comment: You can use % instead of pixels & can use bootstrap to get ready made classes for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Many mobile browsers have issues with this. I doubt if there's a well-known fix for this. What you can try is using the `max-width` attribute. Setting this to some upper bound would help containing the element inside the parent and not overflow.

For responsive designs, here is a good resource that can help:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

I recently came across a website that works flawlessly on mobile as well as desktop browsers.

http://treadsack.com/

Use the developer tools to check the CSS out. Maybe you can get some pointers from there.